# The function must count how many blocks are entered

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming. My task is to make the function of counting how many blocks are typed from the keyboard. And when the block is not closed, to display an error message. I tried so:

```
const void KeyboardToScreen()
{
    char st[80];int br1 = 0, br2 = 0, j;
    puts("Enter the code:");
    while (fgets(st, 80, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (st[j] != '\0')
        {
            if (st[j] == '*') br1++;
            j++;
        }
        if (strstr(st, "{") != NULL)
            br2++;
        if (strstr(st, "}") != NULL)
            br2--;
    }
    if (br2 != NULL)
        printf("ERROR: Block is not closed \n");
    printf("%d %d \n", br1, br2);
    exit(0);
};
```

But when all the blocks are closed my counter "br2" doesn't count how many blocks are entered.

Comment: Include your test data.  it looks like br2 should be zero after reading balanced braces.

Comment: Is `void` allowed to be `const` qualified?

Comment: Note:  don't compare an int (br2) against a pointer (NULL).  NULL is not a general purpose zero value, but a *pointer*.

Comment: @JDługosz Well, it's a null pointer constant, which can either be an integer or a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `br2` to make sure the number of blocks align, correct? Your method of adding one with each open bracket `{` subtracting one with each closing bracket `}` will help you figure out if there are any remaining open brackets, but not with the count.

My suggestions is to simply have a counter for each individual bracket, and compare them at the end.

e.g.:

```
int open_count, closed_count = 0;
if (strstr(st, "{") != NULL)
       open_count++;
if (strstr(st, "}") != NULL)
       closed_count++;

... // finish while loop

if (open_count != closed_count)
       //error
else 
       printf("Count of blocks is %d \n", open_count);
```

Important note: When you're comparing `strstr()` with `NULL` it is because `strstr()` returns a pointer, and if it fails it returns a `NULL` pointer. Do not compare the `int` value of `br2` with `NULL`, it is not a pointer. Instead just check `if (br2 != 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (strstr(st, "{") != NULL)
        br2++;
```

What if you enter a line with more than one '{' on it?  This increments if *any* brace was found, and does not consider *how many* there were.

## some advice

Go through the string one *character* at a time.

```
int count_braces (const char* s)
{
int n= 0;
while (*s) {
   if (*s == '{')  ++n;
   else if (*s == '}') --n;
}
return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually counting the blocks entered. And as JDługosz mentioned, you aren't considering if more than one block begins on a line.

Valid code:

```
{
  {
    //something
  }
}
```

Also valid code:

```
{{ /*something*/ }}
```

Consider this:

```c
int countAllBraces(const char * h, const char * n)
{
    int count = 0;
    const char *tmp = h;
    while( tmp = strstr( tmp, n)){
        //printf( "Position: %d\n", (int)(tmp-h)); //debugging
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

void KeyboardToScreen()
{
    char st[80];int br1 = 0, br2 = 0, j = 0, k = 0, t;
    puts("Enter the code:");
    while (fgets(st, 80, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (st[j] != '\0')
        {
            if (st[j] == '*') br1++;
            j++;
        }
        k += t = countAllBraces(st, "{");
        br2 += t;
        br2 -= countAllBraces(st, "}");
    }
    if (br2 > 0)
        printf("ERROR: Block is not closed \n");
    printf("%d %d \n", br1, k);
    exit(0);
};
```